# BigDecimal attribute changes every page reloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bigdecimal

I was noticed that BigDecimal attribute in my db row changing every page reloading.

```
sum: #<BigDecimal:4add7d0,'0.9E0',9(36)>
ctrl+r
sum: #<BigDecimal:639f200,'0.9E0',9(36)>
ctrl+r
sum: #<BigDecimal:594ceb0,'0.9E0',9(36)>
```

Is it ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the **Object ID** is changing, but not the **value**; all of the results you list use the format `#<BigDecimal:xxxxxxx,'0.9E0',9(36)>`

Each time you reload the page, Rails is creating a *new* `BigDecimal` object instance, but with *the same* data in it. Here's a similar example, using the `irb` console:

```
irb(main):004:0> require 'bigdecimal'
=> true
irb(main):005:0> BigDecimal(9)
=> #<BigDecimal:2aadb50,'0.9E1',9(36)>
irb(main):006:0> BigDecimal(9)
=> #<BigDecimal:2764ab8,'0.9E1',9(36)>
irb(main):007:0> BigDecimal(9)
=> #<BigDecimal:25c3638,'0.9E1',9(36)>
irb(main):008:0>
```